# How to create api documentation using apipie outside the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, documentation, apipie

I am using apipie for API documentation.
The problem I am facing now is that the large amount of information to be provided for documentation is ruining my code structure in the controller.

How can I write the documentation outside the controller file,
so that the code *structure* will be readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find nice explanation on how to use apipie outside controller in this document https://ilyabylich.svbtle.com/apipie-amazing-tool-for-documenting-your-rails-api

To sum things up (example from link):

```
# app/docs/users_doc.rb
module UsersDoc
 # we need the DSL, right?
 extend Apipie::DSL::Concern

 api :GET, '/users', 'List users'
 def show
  # Nothing here, it's just a stub
 end
end

# app/controller/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include UsersDoc

  def show
    # Application code goes here
    # and it overrides blank method
    # from the module
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reference and example, i have a sample application with a controller post when i am implementing apipie as per your guide lines i am getting a error like  uninitialized constant PostController::PostDoc.

Answer (score 0):

`super` also needs to be included in the stubbed actions in the docs. In my app I created a controller that inherits from an existing controller defined in a gem, and if I don't include `super` in the stubbed action, I get unexpected behavior.

So:

```rb
# app/docs/users_doc.rb
module UsersDoc
 # we need the DSL, right?
 extend Apipie::DSL::Concern

 api :GET, '/users', 'List users'
 def show
   super
 end
end

# app/controller/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include UsersDoc

  def show
    # Application code goes here
  end
end
```